# How to ensure for mobile devices gigya does not add gigya-mobile-modal-model?

Tags: javascript, html, gigya

I am trying to implement Gigya for our sites. However, when mobile site loads (registration page), it adds the following class to the html gigya-mobile-modal-model that causes the page showing white page rather than the page.

When the html has no such class gigya-mobile-modal-model, then the page shows the form.

How to ensure for mobile devices gigya does not add gigya-mobile-modal-model?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I added the following in gigya console/css. However, I really will like one of the core Gigya developer to look into this.

```
html.gigya-mobile-modal-mode,
html.gigya-mobile-modal-mode body,
body.gigya-mobile-modal-mode {
    overflow: inherit;
    height: auto;
}
```

And that seemed to fix the bug for me

Answer (score 0):

It would be interesting to know if there is an elegant solution for that.

I had implemented a workaround:
- added some styles for this white overlay
- added some restrictions to the height and position of the popup content
- added some JS to prevent page from 'jumping' after the registration screen has been closed.

Answer (score 0):

I had this exact problem, and this CSS worked for me:

```
html.gigya-mobile-modal-mode,
    html.gigya-mobile-modal-mode body {
    overflow: visible !important;
}
```

Not very elegant, but... it did the trick. YMMV.

Comment: As another user has suggested, I subsequently had to add this CSS in order to fix the problem in Chrome on Android devices:

`html.gigya-mobile-modal-mode body { height: auto !important; }`